# Two lock in amplifiers, almost identical setup, different AC Gain?

Tags: gain, amplitude

I am measuring a voltage output of around ~110 uV for two thermometers. Other than the placement of the thermometers on the sample and the frequency of the lock ins (7225 DSP
at 11.137 Hz, 13.373 Hz), everything else is kept the same but for some reason the lock ins hits at input overload at different AC gains (40dB and 50dB). Could this be a ground loop issue? I'm not quite sure what else it could be. Thank you for your help

Comment: This needs a schematic for proper advice. How are the "thermometers" supplied and what kind are they?

Comment: They are ruthenium oxide thermometers and both ends of the thermometers are connected onto a manganin wire which is connected electrically to the stage (which then is connected to a breakout box where the lock ins can be connected). There's a platinum wire connecting the thermometer to the sample.  I hope this image is sufficient: https://ibb.co/yY2snh1

Comment: Where does the current come from ? Are both thermometers wires in series ?

Comment: I think it is going to be very hard to provide constructive answers without a detailed diagram of your setup and more information about what you're measuring.

Comment: This is a four probe measurement. The heat current is supplied by a high precision current source through a 1k Ohm metal film. We are measuring the voltages across the thermometers (~700 Ohm) with the lockins providing 1 uA.

Comment: So the thermometers are being sourced by the oscillator outputs of the Lockins ? Since the Lockins use the system ground for the return current, there could be some common impedance coupling. But probably not at those current levels. Anyway you could disconnect each Lockin in turn to see if this has an effect on the other reading.